# Reset Mat Radio Group's Mat Radio Buttons to default on a button click

Tags: angular, angular-material, radio-group

I have a set of items to be rated using radio button. I used Mat radio group and Mat radio buttons. Like below, I have to rate games good bad or none. After applying the changes all the radio buttons should be defaulted to None. Please help me to complete this task.

**Template**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let s of sites">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
    {{s}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
    <mat-radio-group>
      <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let o of options; let j=index"
        [checked]="j===0"
        [value]="o">
        {{o}}
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
  </div>
</ng-container>
<button (click)="resetRadio()">Apply Changes</button>
```

**TypeScript code**

```
  sites: string[] = ['Tekken', 'Street Fighter', 'DBZ'];
  options: string[] = ['None', 'Good', 'Bad'];

  resetRadio(): void {
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best, easy and safe way is to use **Angular template driven forms** or **Reactive Forms**...but for your requirement you can use *@ViewChildren* decorator to target MatButtonGroup and set 'None' value.

this is an example : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-components-demo-iptopj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Using formGroup, you can use

```
private form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({....

resetRadio(): void {
    this.form.reset();
}
```